# Python Catching Popen Output

Tags: python, multithreading, popen, scp, stderr

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with my Python script exiting without any error messages. Based on my debugging it is happening around a popen() call to scp a file to a server.

The code was (I was not the original author):

```
logMessage(LEVEL_INFO, "copyto is " + copyto)
pid = Popen(["scp", "-i", "/root/.ssh/id_rsa", "/usr/gpsw/gpslog" + self.node_addr, copyto], stdout=PIPE)
__s = pid.communicate()[0]
logMessage(LEVEL_INFO, "GPS log SCP complete")
```

In an attempt to debug I enhanced it to:

```
logMessage(LEVEL_INFO, "copyto is " + copyto)
pid = Popen(["scp", "-i", "/root/.ssh/id_rsa", "/usr/gpsw/gpslog" + self.node_addr, copyto], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = pid.communicate()
if out:
    print "[" + self.node_addr + "] stdout of pid: " + str(out)
if err:
    print "[" + self.node_addr + "] stdout of pid: " + str(err)
print "[" + self.node_addr + "] returncode of pid: " + str(pid.returncode)
logMessage(LEVEL_INFO, "GPS log SCP complete")
```

Here is my console output: 
(The pattern should be 5dda77, 5dd9fa, 5dda0d repeatedly. This is based on physical events)

```
[5dda77] returncode of pid: 0
[5dd9fa] returncode of pid: 0
[5dda0d] returncode of pid: 0
[5dda77] returncode of pid: 0
[5dd9fa] returncode of pid: 0
[5dda0d] returncode of pid: 0
# (the script exited and I'm back at the prompt)
```

And here is my log output:

```
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dda77
INFO GPS log SCP complete
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dd9fa
INFO GPS log SCP complete
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dda0d
INFO GPS log SCP complete
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dda77
INFO GPS log SCP complete
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dd9fa
INFO GPS log SCP complete
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dda0d
INFO GPS log SCP complete
INFO copyto is root@192.168.20.1:/usr/scu/datafiles/gpslog5dda77
```

So based on the log and output data. I believe something is going wrong during the SCP because the Python script crashes before it logs "GPS log SCP complete". What is interesting though is I see on the server end the file was copied entirely. So two questions:

1. Am I using popen incorrectly?
2. Why am I not seeing any error messages in stderr?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
This script should *never* exit. There is no "normal exit" of the process. It should run indefinitely servicing requests from the server to retrieve data from GPS nodes that are available.

The main loop code is:

```
stop_flags = 0

... (API for server and GPS nodes to interact with)

def main():

    ... (System initialization)

    while stop_flags == 0:
        # listen for messages
        xmlrpcserver.handle_request()
        comm.poll()
    if stop_flags == STOP_FLAG_RESTART:
        # suppress Pylint warning for reimport of Popen,PIPE
        # pylint: disable-msg=W0404
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        # use this instead of call to suppress output
        pid = Popen(["/etc/init.d/S999snap",
                    "restart"],
                    stdout=PIPE)
        __s = pid.communicate()[0]
    if stop_flags == STOP_FLAG_REBOOT:
        # suppress Pylint warning for reimport of Popen,PIPE
        # pylint: disable-msg=W0404
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        # use this instead of call to suppress output
        pid = Popen(["reboot"],
                    stdout=PIPE)
        __s = pid.communicate()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure there is any stderr to capture? Have you tried running the failing command manually from bash to see, or are you just assuming that there must be something there?

Comment: Meanwhile, what makes you think it "crashes"? Is there a segfault? Or an exception traceback? Most likely, it exits just fine, and the only reason `logMessage` isn't showing the last message is that it's some custom code you wrote that never flushes closes the log file.

Comment: How do you know python is crashing?  You say there is no error messages and the scp was successful, so I'm curious why you think it is crashing.

Comment: @abarnert I am assuming there must be something here because this it the point where the script exists. If you look at the log output you'll see the third instance to the start of the GPS log copy for 5dda77, but the script exits before prints the return code for that PID

Comment: @SethMMorton I know the script crashes because this script should run forever. Processing GPS nodes as they become available. It exiting without any kind of segfault or other error. It should never exit at all.

Comment: @ayuelkenbeck please be more specific. I am supplying a full source and destination path to SCP

Comment: You will have to show us a complete, running example, stripped down as small as possible such that it still demonstrates the problem. The code you showed us obviously only runs one time; if the code that's supposed to make it run forever isn't working, you have to show us that code.

Comment: @ayuelkenbeck: If that were the problem it wouldn't work multiple times and then fail once, would it?

Comment: @abarnet Ok, I must've misunderstood the problem. Sorry.

Comment: @abarnert The code is 2K lines and that isn't even the whole story. The main loop of the script waits for a command from the server notifying it that a GPS node is available to process. It then handles that and responds back to the server. I know that the problem is here at the point of SCP... I just can't figure out why. Is there any other code I could instrument to help debug this? I'm not that familiar with Python.

Comment: That's why I said "stripped down as small as possible such that it still demonstrates the problem". That's the first step toward debugging almost anything, but that's especially true if you want others to do the debugging for you. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more information.

Comment: Meanwhile, how do you know that the problem is here at the point of SCP? And please, answer all of the questions, and address all of the issues, that everyone has raised, instead of just picking a few at random. Since you haven't commented at all about whether you flush the log file, whether you're running this in a daemon thread, why you think threading is relevant in the first place, etc., the most likely possibility is that the problem is in one of those areas, which means we can't debug it. If you know that's not true, you have to tell us that.

Comment: Based on your new edit, it looks like once `stop_flags != 0` the loop exits goes to the conditionals, then will quit.  I now have two questions: 1) Is there an indentation error and those conditionals should be in the loop, because if not this will **definitely** not run forever, and 2) how is `stop_flags` set inside the `while` loop?

Comment: @SethMMorton I was trying to provide information. But I was typing fast. Yes that is an indentation error. The stop_flags global is only modified when the server is in the process of being shutdown. Then, and only then, will it send a signal to the Python script to exit. That is _not_ happening.

Comment: Are there any `try: except:` blocks in the `xmlrpcserver.handle_request()` function that catch an error and not print anything?  That could be a cause for not seeing any error message.

Comment: Rather than making us keep guessing where the problem is, ask you to show us more code, wait for you to show us half the relevant code, ask again for the rest, etc., can you please just give us a complete (and ideally stripped-down) example?

Answer (score -1):

You are using `Popen` just fine.

And, although it's impossible to be sure unless you test the same commands yourself in some other way (e.g., just run them interactively via `bash`), it's most likely that you're not seeing anything in `stderr` because there is nothing being printed to `stderr`.

It's almost certainly not crashing, unless you've got a segfault, exception traceback, or some other reason to believe otherwise. You said that it finished all of its work successfully, so what makes you think it crashed?

As for the last log message not showing up… you have to show us your custom `logMessage` code if you want a definite answer, but I'm willing to be you never `flush` or `close` the log file.

Finally, you've tagged your question `multithreading`, which could easily be relevant. Again, without even a description of how you're doing the threading, much less actual code, we can't do anything but guess, but you could, e.g., be running this code in a `daemon=True` thread, and then exiting the main thread.

Comment: This script is, in fact, crashing. There is no termination to it. Its design is to run forever processing GPS nodes as they become available. And frequently, it crashes after SCPing data from one of those nodes to the server. The Python script exits and there are no errors logged or displayed. But it always occurs at this exact point in the code after the SCP command and I never get a return code from the SCP PID.

Comment: First, "exiting normally" is not crashing. Second, how do you expect us to debug whatever is causing it to terminate without seeing the code that should never terminate?